# Frameworks similar to angularjs for android apps?

Tags: android, angularjs, android-layout

AngularJS has some useful directives like ng-repeat that allow us to render repetitive elements easily, is there something that simplifies this on Android apps? It would be useful for creating something like a newsfeed, or message board, etc.

Comment: you can still use AngularJS to create Android apps and then publish them on Google Play Store.

Comment: @PAC are there any guides for getting started?

Comment: "is there something that simplifies this on Android apps?" -- um, Java and a `for` loop? Or `AdapterView` classes like `ListView`? Or `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ionic framework.
Refer :  http://www.ionicframework.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is Ionic like Monika said or if you want another one less complicated then you can try Mobile Angular Ui http://mobileangularui.com/